# Vectorization for meshgrid in Matlab (or Octave)

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, octave, vectorization

Vectorized code in Matlab runs much faster than a for loop (see [Parallel computing in Octave on a single machine -- package and example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520495/parallel-computing-in-octave-on-a-single-machine-package-and-example/10543033#10543033) for concrete results in Octave)

With that said, is there a way to vectorize the code shown next in Matlab or Octave?

```
x = -2:0.01:2;
y = -2:0.01:2;
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = sin(xx.^2-yy.^2);
```

Comment: Check out the just added `bsxfun` implementation, that also talks about using GPU [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25162350/3293881)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

As pointed out by @Jonas, there are a few options available in MATLAB, and which works best depends on a few factors such as:

- How large is your problem
- How many machines you have available
- Do you have a GPU
- Does MATLAB already multithread the operations

Many elementwise operations are multithreaded in MATLAB now - in which case, there's generally little point using PARFOR (unless you have multiple machines and MATLAB Distributed Computing Server licences available).

Truly huge problems that need the memory of multiple machines can benefit from [distributed arrays](http://www.mathworks.co.uk/help/toolbox/distcomp/bquvksw.html).

Using the GPU can beat the multithreaded performance of a single machine if your problem is of a suitable size and type for GPU computation. Vectorized code tends to be the most natural fit for parallelization via the GPU. For example, you could write your code using `gpuArray`s from Parallel Computing Toolbox like so and have everything run on the GPU.

```
x = parallel.gpu.GPUArray.colon(-2,0.01,2);
y = x;
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y); % xx and yy are on the GPU
z = arrayfun( @(u, v) sin(u.*u-v.*v), xx, yy );
```

I converted the final line there into an `arrayfun` call as that is more efficient when using `gpuArray`s.

Comment: Great! You are right in that Matlab automatically multithreads the computation I gave above.  I was running the computation from home without the Parallel Computing Toolbox, and just now I ran it on a machine with the toolbox and it was done in parallel.

And thanks for the GPU example...I have never used a GPU, but I suspect one will come in handy in the future, and it's good to know the code seems straightforward

Comment: Though, its an old post, I was able to implement it with bsxfun on GPU and got good speedups. Posted a solution here on the same!

Answer (score 7):

## Vectorization for `meshgrid` and `ndgrid`

If you are still interested in finding a vectorized implementation to make the `meshgrid` based code in the problem faster, let me suggest a vectorized method with `bsxfun` and it's GPU ported version. I strongly believe that people must look into `vectorization with GPUs` as a promising option to speed up `MATLAB` codes. Codes that employ `meshgrid` or `ndgrid` and whose outputs are to be  operated with some elementwise operation setup a perfect ground to employ `bsxfun` into those codes. To add to that, the use of GPU with `bsxfun`, that lets it work on the elements independently with hundreds and thousands of CUDA cores available, makes it just perfect for GPU implementation.

For your specific problem, the inputs were -

```
x = -2:0.01:2;
y = -2:0.01:2;
```

Next, you had -

```
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = sin(xx.^2-yy.^2);
```

With `bsxfun`, this becomes a one-liner -

```
z = sin(bsxfun(@minus,x.^2,y.^2.'));
```

## Benchmarking

GPU benchmarking tips were taken from [Measure and Improve GPU Performance](http://www.mathworks.in/help/distcomp/measure-and-improve-gpu-performance.html).

```
%// Warm up GPU call with insignificant small scalar inputs
temp1 = sin_sqdiff_vect2(0,0);

N_arr = [50 100 200 500 1000 2000 3000]; %// array elements for N (datasize)
timeall = zeros(3,numel(N_arr));

for k = 1:numel(N_arr)
    N = N_arr(k);
    x = linspace(-20,20,N);
    y = linspace(-20,20,N);

    f = @() sin_sqdiff_org(x,y);%// Original CPU code
    timeall(1,k) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() sin_sqdiff_vect1(x,y);%// Vectorized CPU code
    timeall(2,k) = timeit(f);
    clear f

    f = @() sin_sqdiff_vect2(x,y);%// Vectorized GPU(GTX 750Ti) code
    timeall(3,k) = gputimeit(f);
    clear f
end

%// Display benchmark results
figure,hold on, grid on
plot(N_arr,timeall(1,:),'-b.')
plot(N_arr,timeall(2,:),'-ro')
plot(N_arr,timeall(3,:),'-kx')
legend('Original CPU','Vectorized CPU','Vectorized GPU (GTX 750 Ti)')
xlabel('Datasize (N) ->'),ylabel('Time(sec) ->')
```

**Associated functions**

```
%// Original code
function z = sin_sqdiff_org(x,y)
[xx,yy] = meshgrid(x,y);
z = sin(xx.^2-yy.^2);
return;

%// Vectorized CPU code
function z = sin_sqdiff_vect1(x,y)
z = sin(bsxfun(@minus,x.^2,y.^2.')); %//'
return;

%// Vectorized GPU code
function z = sin_sqdiff_vect2(x,y)
gx = gpuArray(x);
gy = gpuArray(y);
gz = sin(bsxfun(@minus,gx.^2,gy.^2.')); %//'
z =  gather(gz);
return;
```

## Results

[image]

## Conclusions

As the results show, vectorized method with GPU shows good performance improvement which is  about `4.3x` against the vectorized CPU code and `6x` against the original code. Please keep in mind that GPU has to overcome a minimum overhead that is required with it's setting up, so at least a decent sized input is needed to see the improvement. Hopefully, people would explore more of `vectorization with GPUs`, as it could not be stressed enough!

Answer (score 6):

In Matlab, the only way to get built-in vectorized functions to multithread is to wait for MathWorks to [implement them](http://www.mathworks.com/support/solutions/en/data/1-4PG4AN/?solution=1-4PG4AN) as such.

Alternatively, you can write the vectorized computation as a loop, and run them in parallel using `parfor`.

Finally, a number of functions are [GPU-enabled](http://www.mathworks.com/help/toolbox/distcomp/bsic4fr-1.html#bsloua3-1), so with access to the parallel processing toolbox you can parallelize these operations, including the subtraction and the element-wise power.

Comment: `for` loops in Matlab tend to be slower than vectorized calculations.  So the ideal situation for optimal performance seems to be to try and parallelize vectorized code, if possible.

Comment: @dblazevski: `parfor` helps, but you may want to look into running some code on the GPU. See my edit. Also, in recent versions of Matlab, `for`-loops have become surprisingly fast.

Comment: True.  I tested the example given in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10520495/parallel-computing-in-octave-on-a-single-machine-package-and-example/10543033#10543033
I even refined the grid a lot.  In Matlab the `for` loop was slower, but only about 5 times as much as the vectorized version.  In Octave, the `for` loop code took *much* longer (like over 100 times longer...).  I've been curious about GPUs for a while now, though haven't given them a try...do you know a starting point to learn to use/program a GPU?

Comment: @dblazevski: If you want to use the GPU from Matlab, look at the documentation of the Parallel Computing Toolbox. Otherwise, look at the CUDA documentation and their examples.

Comment: I was able to get really good speedup with `bsxfun`on GPU implementation and posted a solution with it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25162350/3293881)