# Problem with R performance when I assign new attribute to two different graphs

Tags: r, performance, igraph

In my R script, i have a graph object "flights" and then I assign to the edges an attribute "type" with this code:

```
stats <- summary(E(graph)$weight)

# 1st threshfirstThresh <- as.double(stats["1st Qu."]) 
firstThresh

# 2nd thresh 
secondThresh <- as.double(stats["3rd Qu."])

for (i in 1:length(E(flights))){
  if(E(graph)[i]$weight < firstThresh)
    E(graph)[i]$type <- "C"
  else if (E(graph)[i]$weight < secondThresh)
    E(graph)[i]$type <- "M"
  else
    E(graph)[i]$type <- "L"
  cat(i , " - ")
}
```

Why with this code a **single iteration** of the "for" loop is really much slower in  if I use another graph with an higher number of nodes and edges?

In particular, i made a simple benchmark in this way:

```
start.time <- Sys.time()
...Relevent codes...
end.time <- Sys.time()
time.taken <- end.time - start.time
time.taken
```

These are the results for **200 loop iterations** on the two graphs:

- for the first graph: **0.5541661 secs**
- for the first graph: **26.57538 secs**

Why there's so much difference even if the code is the same?

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input that can be used to test and verify possible solutions.

Comment: @MrFlick i have the graph stored in a file, and they have 6000 and 1500 nodes. How can i post a reproducible example?

Comment: Demonstrate the issue using a small sample graph you can provide code for, and maybe a larger graph with more nodes that can be simulated easily. We need to be able to run your code on **something** in order to try to improve it.

Comment: i don't understand ... in the code i don't use any attribute of the graph, i only assign a new attribute , how a graph example can be usefull? i don't even know how to provide the example of the graph because it's an entire graphml file that i cannot attach here

Comment: Could you show us the result of: `str(graph)`? Is it possible to reproduce the result with a random graph?

Comment: Result of str:
- First graph : Class 'igraph'  hidden list of 10
 $ : num 235
 $ : logi FALSE
 $ : num [1:2101] 136 ...
 $ : num [1:2101] 0 ...
 $ : num [1:2101] 58 ...
 $ : num [1:2101] 267...
 $ : num [1:236] 0  ...
 $ : num [1:236] 0  ...
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : num [1:3] 1 0 1
  ..$ : Named list()
  ..$ :List of 4
  .. ..$ x      : num [1:235] -9 ..
  .. ..$ tooltip: chr [1:235] "LIT(lngx=-5,laty=3)" ...
  .. ..$ y      : num [1:235] -347  ...
  .. ..$ id     : chr [1:235] "0"  ...
  ..$ :List of 1
  .. ..$ id: chr [1:2101] "0" ...
 $ :<environment: 0x0000022b1c333f70>

Comment: second graph (part 1): 
Class 'igraph'  hidden list of 10
 $ : num 6072
 $ : logi TRUE
 $ : num [1:66923] 2262...
 $ : num [1:66923] 2284...
 $ : num [1:66923] 17042...
 $ : num [1:66923] 17068...
 $ : num [1:6073] 0...
 $ : num [1:6073] 0...
 $ :List of 4
  ..$ : num [1:3] 1...
  ..$ : Named list()
  ..$ :List of 13
  .. ..$ name : chr [1:6072] "Goroka Airport"...
  .. ..$ city          : chr [1:6072] "Goroka"...
  .. ..$ country       : chr [1:6072] "Papua"...
  .. ..$ ICAO          : chr [1:6072] "AYGA"...

Comment: second graph (part 2)
.. ..$ latitude      : num [1:6072] -6...
  .. ..$ longitude     : num [1:6072] 145...
  .. ..$ altitude      : num [1:6072] 5...
  .. ..$ id            : chr [1:6072] "n0"...
  ..$ :List of 8
  .. ..$ airline             : chr [1:66923] "2B"...
  .. ..$ airlineID           : chr [1:66923] "410"...
  .. ..$ sourceAirportID     : chr [1:66923] ...
  .. ..$ destinationAirportID: chr [1:66923]...
  .. ..$ weight: num [1:66923] 1509 1042 449 771 1340 ...
 $ :<environment: 0x0000022b265e1c28>

Comment: _Why with this code a single iteration of the "for" loop is really much slower in if I use another graph with an higher number of nodes?_ You are iterating through edges, not nodes. Does the graph where the operation is faster have more edges as well? Or only more nodes?

Comment: @Szabolcs it also has more edges. But I think that it doesn't matter, I executed the benchmark with only 200 edges in both graphs

Comment: If this is so, it is very unusual. As others said, please produce a minimal example.

Comment: Minimal example (1)  `n <- 235; graph1 <- sample_gnm(n, 2121)`. Takes 0.17 seconds.
(2) `n <- 6072; graph2 <- sample_gnm(6072, 66923)`. Takes 46 seconds. 
This is Windows11. As mentioned in the `igraph` forum,` igraph` is slow for single updates.

Comment: Set weight to: `E(graph1)$weight <- round(runif(ecount(graph1)) * 100)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Regarding `igraph` efficiency see: https://igraph.discourse.group/t/igraph-is-much-slower-than-networkx-when-generating-a-graph/853.

Much faster is to vectorize the coding:

```
set.seed(2023)
library(igraph)

firstThresh  <- 20
secondThresh <- 80

system.time({
n <- 6072; m <- 66923
graph           <- sample_gnm(n, m)
E(graph)$weight <- round(runif(m) * 100)

E(graph)$type <- "L"
E(graph)$type[which(E(graph)$weight < secondThresh)] <- "M"
E(graph)$type[which(E(graph)$weight < firstThresh)]  <- "C"
})
# Benchmark system.time.
# user  system elapsed 
# 0.02    0.00    0.02

print.igraph(graph, full="auto.print.lines=0")
# IGRAPH d66a81f U-W- 6072 66923 -- Erdos-Renyi (gnm) graph
# + attr: name (g/c), type (g/c), loops (g/l), m (g/n), weight (e/n), typ (e/c)
```

**Surprise**

```
library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
"one" = (E(graph)[weight < secondTresh]$type <- "M"),
"two" = (E(graph)$type[which(E(graph)$weight < secondTresh)] <- "M")
)
# Unit: microseconds
# expr    min      lq     mean  median      uq     max neval
#  one 2648.5 2776.75 3607.604 2851.95 4149.95 19895.9   100
#  two  847.3  978.10 1364.860 1019.30 1317.25  3171.7   100
```

I have no explanation for the performance difference.
However: [In base R, why is selecting column, then filtering rows faster than vice versa: filter rows, then select column?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75775273/in-base-r-why-is-selecting-column-then-filtering-rows-faster-than-vice-versa).

**Update - Why is vectorized code faster?**
See also: [Why is vectorization faster](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16902902/why-is-vectorization-faster).

My casual answer:
Consider x <- y. It is much clearer if the coding is the same regardless of whether x consists of one or more values.
In my experience, "vectorized" programming is more difficult to implement but less prone to errors. It is either right or completely wrong.
Avoiding for-loops is also faster. The reason is that the time to execute an assignment statement is mainly determined by overhead, as we can see in the following example.

```
a <- 0; b <- 0
n <- 1E4; va <- runif(n); vb <- runif(n)

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(
"single"    = (a <- b),
"multi"     = (va <- vb )
)

## Unit: nanoseconds
##    expr min  lq mean median  uq  max neval
##  single   0 100   87    100 100  500   100
##   multi   0 100  112    100 100 1400   100
object.size(va)
## 80048 bytes
```

**But more importantly in this example**

Within the loop, the graph is copied twice in each iteration, a total of 2 times the number of flights.

```
tracemem(graph)
E(graph)[i]$type <- "M"
untracemem(graph)
# tracemem[0x00000241f1305358 -> 0x00000241f1329f78]: 
# tracemem[0x00000241f1329f78 -> 0x00000241f1329ec8]: i_set_edge_attr E<-
```

Comment: this works... why the vectorized code is faster?

Comment: See my comment.

Comment: Note @Szabolcs' solution is more elegant and concise. Therefore use `E(graph)[weight < secondTresh]$type <- "M"` instead of `E(graph)$type[which(E(graph)$weight < secondThresh)] <- "M"`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the following approach, and let us know if it is faster. I did not benchmark this, since I do not have your graph.

```
> g <- make_(ring(10), with_edge_(weight=1:10))

> E(g)$weight
 [1]  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10

> E(g)$kind <- 'C'
> E(g)[weight < 3]$kind <- 'A'
> E(g)[3 <= weight & weight < 5]$kind <- 'B'

> E(g)$kind
 [1] "A" "A" "B" "B" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C" "C"
```

Be cautious with `type` as an attribute name. When applied to vertices, it should be of type logical, as it has a special interpretation as encoding the two partitions of a bipartite graph.

Comment: So you think that the problem is the attribute name?

Comment: @xSambx02 No, the attribute name will not cause performance issues. I clarified the answer. I'll leave the benchmarking to you, but it'll be nice if you can report back with your results.