# Reshaping a matrix

Tags: matlab, matrix, reshape

I have a matrix that looks something like this:

```
a=[1   1   2   2   3   3   4   4;
   1.5 1.5 2.5 2.5 3.5 3.5 4.5 4.5]
```

what I would like to do is reshape this ie.

What I want is to take the `2x2` matrices next to one another and put them underneath each other.

So get:

```
b=[1     1;
   1.5   1.5;
   2     2;
   2.5   2.5;
   3     3;
   3.5   3.5;
   4     4;
   4.5   4.5]
```

but I can't seem to manipulate the `reshape` function to do this for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

edit: the single line version might be a bit complicated, so I've also added one based on a for loop

2 reshapes and a permute should do it (we first split the matrices and store them in 3d), and then stack them. In order to stack them we first need to permute the dimensions (similar to a transpose).

```
>> reshape(permute(reshape(a,2,2,4),[1 3 2]),8,2)

ans =

    1.0000    1.0000
    1.5000    1.5000
    2.0000    2.0000
    2.5000    2.5000
    3.0000    3.0000
    3.5000    3.5000
    4.0000    4.0000
    4.5000    4.5000
```

the for loop based version is a bit more straight forward. We create an empty array of the correct size, and then insert each of the 2x2 matrices separately:

```
b=zeros(8,2);
for i=1:4,
  b((2*i-1):(2*i),:) = a(:,(2*i-1):(2*i));
end
```

Comment: Loops are evil in Matlab - they say.

Comment: Loops indeed are generally slower. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14035365/why-does-vectorized-code-run-faster-than-for-loops-in-matlab

Comment: @remus and Lanting - that's actually no longer the case. With the JIT compiler, a loop (assuming preallocation) in many cases will actually be very fast these, sometimes even beating the vectorizations  http://www.matlabtips.com/matlab-is-no-longer-slow-at-for-loops/.