# what is the purpose of the @ symbol in front of a variable in octave?

Tags: syntax, octave, at-sign

For example:

```
model = svmTrain(X, y, C, @(x1, x2) gaussianKernel(x1, x2, sigma));
```

Disclaimer: This is from the Coursera ML class, but it's nearly impossible to search for the @ symbol conventionally.

Answer (score 5):

`@` prefixes the definition of an [anonymous function](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Anonymous-Functions.html).

Answer (score 1):

Also, `@` is used to demark a [function handle](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/doc/interpreter/Function-Handles.html).

Comment: Not in this context. -1

Comment: There is a mismatch between the question title and the contextual example given, being the lack of parentheses in the title. This answer does, in fact, address a possible answer for the title as written. Perhaps an update to reflect this by someone would help solve the ambiguity.